# Environment to write lines in a screenplay fashion?

Tags: packages

Assuming that one is writing a scientific document and at some point is interested in writing a couple of lines, ex.

- Player: Hi! How are you?
- NPC: Nice, thanks!

in a screenplay fashion. Is there some nice way/environment in order to achieve that?

Answer (score 4):

Probably `tcolorbox` can give you a start point...

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example

\begin{document}

\section{A section}

\lipsum[1-3]

\section{Fancy section}

\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=yellow!50]
\textbf{Player}: Hi! How are you?
\end{tcolorbox}
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=green!50]
\textbf{NPC}: Nice, thanks!
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

You can also choose some fancy font inside the `tcolorbox` environment to get something like

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example

\begin{document}

\section{A section}

\lipsum[1-3]

\section{Fancy section}

\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=yellow!50]
\textbf{Player}: \fontfamily{pzc}\selectfont Hi! How are you?
\end{tcolorbox}
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=green!50]
\textbf{NPC}: \fontfamily{pzc}\selectfont Nice, thanks!
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

As the question is so open, this is my suggestion, using the `bclogo` package:
[image: MWE]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{microtype}  
\usepackage{lipsum}  % dummy text
\usepackage[tikz]{bclogo}

\newcommand\FancyBox[2]{%
\begin{bclogo}[couleur=yellow!15!orange!05,
logo=\Huge\bcplume, arrondi=0.3, ombre=true,
couleurOmbre=gray, 
couleurBarre=orange!30,
couleurBord=orange!30!gray!60,
marge=12, blur]%
{\hfill#1\hfill}%title
\bigskip
\begin{description}
#2
\end{description}
\end{bclogo}
}%

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[1]

\FancyBox{The salutation}
{\item[Player:] Hi! How are you?
\item[NPC:] Nice, thanks!}

\lipsum[3]

\FancyBox{The discussion}
{\item[Player:] \lipsum[2]
\item[NPC:] \lipsum[2]}

\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Without anything fancy and with `tabular`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{R}{p{\dimexpr0.88\textwidth-2\tabcolsep\relax}}
\newcolumntype{L}{p{0.12\textwidth}}

\newenvironment{play}[1][Player]{%
\noindent\tabular{@{}L>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}R@{}}
\textbf{#1:} &%
}%
{\endtabular}%

\begin{document}

\section{A section}

\begin{play}[Player]
 Hi! How are you?
\end{play}
\begin{play}[NPC]
Nice, thanks!
\end{play}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Let us add color:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{R}{p{\dimexpr0.88\textwidth-2\tabcolsep\relax}}
\newcolumntype{L}{p{0.12\textwidth}}

\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{play}{O{Player}O{blue}}{%
\noindent\tabular{@{}L>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}R@{}}
\rowcolor{#2!40}\textbf{#1:} &%
}%
{\endtabular}%

%%syntax
%%\begin{play}[<who talks>][<color>]        %%% default talker is Player and color is blue
%%   <conversation>
%%\end{play}

\begin{document}

\section{A section}

\begin{play}
 Hi! How are you? This line will go over two lines and come to the second line as usual
\end{play}
\begin{play}[NPC][yellow]
Nice, thanks!
\end{play}
\begin{play}[ABC][green]
Nice, thanks!
\end{play}

\end{document}
```

[image]