# Create a mdframe with large icon in the text body

Tags: mdframed, fontawesome

I'm trying to replicate a common pattern in programming books, where authors use to create few designs for brief, emphasized text portions that differ in the icon/image used, e.g.

[image: Packt Publishing style]

or also:

[image]

and finally:

[image]

Each of the above styles comes from books where 3, 4 versions are used (changing only the icon, that carries a different meaning)

So far I've only been able to create a very basic mdframe example to be used in a `scrbook` class:

```
\documentclass[
    letterpaper,
    12pt,
    oneside
]{scrbook}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage[framemethod=PSTricks]{mdframed}

\begin{document}

\mdfdefinestyle{roundframe}{
  leftmargin=1cm,
  rightmargin=1cm, 
  innerleftmargin=2cm,
  innerrightmargin=2cm,
  roundcorner=10pt
 }

\newmdenv[style=roundframe]{framedaside}

\lipsum[1]  

\begin{framedaside}
In any right triangle, the area of the square whose side is the hypotenuse is equal to the sum of the areas of the squares whose sides are the two legs.
\end{framedaside}

\lipsum[1]  

\end{document}
```

[image]

I'm after a way to create few `newmdenv` where I would:

```
\begin{infoaside}
% ...
\end{infoaside}

\begin{warningaside}
%...
\end{warningaside}
```

Each of them would have an image (or ideally a FontAwesome icon) in the top-left part of the mdframe, and the body – either text, listings, etc. – padded accordingly, as in the examples provided.

Any help in guiding me through this would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Check this answer please https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/501680/120578 (and all the other answers in this topic)

Comment: Thanks! I did search a lot on this subject, but I've always been looking for "asides" and mdframed, it has never occurred to me that they might be called "highlight boxes". [awesomebox](http://ctan.org/pkg/awesomebox) might do the trick in the short term, then I may want to borrow other solutions provided in the thread you've linked. Thanks again.

Comment: Welcome @user1625148 ... Happy TeXing

Comment: Look also tthe `bclogo` package https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/163249/11604 and

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's easy to get what you want with `tcolorbox`.

Starting from this [answer by Ignasi](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/319355/tcolorbox-breakable-option-not-working), I've created two kinds of boxes, `borderbox` and `boxwithoutborder`, which have a mandatory argument you can use to put the image/symbol you like.
These boxes are both breakable through the pages.

```
\documentclass[
    letterpaper,
    12pt,
    oneside
    ]{scrbook}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}
%From: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/319355/tcolorbox-breakable-option-not-working
\newtcolorbox{borderbox}[2][]{
    enhanced jigsaw,
    breakable,
    notitle,
    sharpish corners,
    before skip=\baselineskip,
    opacityback=0,
    opacityframe=0,
    leftupper=1.5cm,
    overlay unbroken={
        \node[anchor=north west] at ([xshift=2mm,yshift=-2mm]frame.north west) {#2};
        \draw[very thick] ([xshift=10pt]frame.north west) -| (frame.south west) -- ++(10pt,0);
        \draw[very thick] ([xshift=-10pt]frame.north east) -| (frame.south east) -- ++(-10pt,0);
        },
    overlay first={
        \node[anchor=north west] at ([xshift=2mm,yshift=-2mm]frame.north west) {#2};
        \draw[very thick] ([xshift=10pt]frame.north west) -| (frame.south west);
        \draw[very thick] ([xshift=-10pt]frame.north east) -| (frame.south east);
        },
    overlay middle={
        \draw[very thick] (frame.north west) -- (frame.south west);
        \draw[very thick] (frame.north east) -- (frame.south east);
        },
    overlay last={
        \draw[very thick] (frame.north west) -- (frame.south west) -- ++(10pt,0);
        \draw[very thick] (frame.north east) -- (frame.south east) -- ++(-10pt,0);
        },
    #1
}
\newtcolorbox{boxwithoutborder}[2][]{
    enhanced jigsaw,
    breakable,
    notitle,
    sharpish corners,
    before skip=\baselineskip,
    opacityback=0,
    opacityframe=0,
    leftupper=1.5cm,
    overlay unbroken={
        \node[anchor=north west] at ([xshift=2mm,yshift=-2mm]frame.north west) {#2};
        },
    overlay first={
        \node[anchor=north west] at ([xshift=2mm,yshift=-2mm]frame.north west) {#2}; },
    #1
}
\begin{document}

    \lipsum[2]
    \begin{borderbox}{\resizebox{1cm}{!}{\faCogs}}
        \lipsum[2]
    \end{borderbox}
    \lipsum[2]
    \begin{borderbox}{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-a}}
        \lipsum
    \end{borderbox}
    \lipsum[2]
    \begin{boxwithoutborder}{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-a}}
        \lipsum[2]
    \end{boxwithoutborder}
    \lipsum[2]
    \begin{boxwithoutborder}{\resizebox{1cm}{!}{\faCogs}}
        \lipsum
    \end{boxwithoutborder}
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understand your question. Would you like to get something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{awesomebox}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
 \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\lipsum[1][1-2]

\awesomebox{0pt}{\faCogs}{black}{\lipsum[1][1-3]
\begin{itemize}
\itemsep-.5em 
    \item This is the first paragraph;
    \item This is the second paragraph
\end{itemize}
\lipsum[2][3-5]}

\lipsum[1][1-3]
\end{document}
```

To have another symbol you can consider the best answer of the user @Schrödinger's cat at this link: [Speedometer as a symbol into awesomebox](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/508078/speedometer-as-a-symbol-into-awesomebox)

Comment: Thanks! `awesomebox` looks great, alas it doesn't span on multiple pages (I've requested it as a feat. to the author's github repo). I am currently trying to modify an example I've found on the `mdframed` package but I'd need guidance: what's the proper way, should I open a new thread or just go with the "answer your question" button? Thanks!